# UpdateCursor error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have a problem with arcpy.UpdateCursor. The script has to fill a table with data of an xml file. The script is the following:

```
newtable = arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(selectlayer,outputlocation,tablename)
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"R_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"G_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"B_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"C_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"M_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"Y_value","TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management(newtable,"K_value","TEXT") 
attr = parent.iter('String').next().text
    r = parent.iter('R').next().text
    g = parent.iter('G').next().text
    b = parent.iter('B').next().text
    c = 1 - float(r) / 255
    m = 1 - float(g) / 255
    y = 1 - float(b) / 255
    min_cmy = min(c, m, y)
    c = (c - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
    m = (m - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
    y = (y - min_cmy) / (1 - min_cmy)
    k = min_cmyc_value = int(round(c * 100))
    m_value = int(round(m * 100))
    y_value = int(round(y * 100))
    k_value = int(round(k * 100))
    query = "%s = '%s'" %(symbolfield,attr)
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(newtable, query) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            row.setValue("R_value", r)
            row.setValue("G_value", g)
            row.setValue("B_value", b)
            row.setValue("C_value", str(c_value))
            row.setValue("M_value", str(m_value))
            row.setValue("Y_value", str(y_value))
            row.setValue("K_value", str(k_value))
            rows.updateRow(row)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
```

Actually, if I print the variables, I get them, and I also can create the attribute table, but it's empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't specified any fields in your UpdateCursor - you've specified the table and the query but there should be a list of fields there too

Comment: it appears you're trying to set fields using the old `arcpy.UpdateCursor` method while actually using an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're mixing the syntax of the old [`arcpy.UpdateCursor()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm) with the newer [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

Try changing your cursor to be something like:

```
updateFields = ["R_value", "G_value", "B_value", "C_value", "M_value", "Y_value", "K_value"]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(newtable, updateFields, query) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        row[0] = r
        row[1] = g
        row[2] = b)
        row[3] = str(c_value)
        row[4] = str(m_value)
        row[5] = str(y_value)
        row[6] = str(k_value)
        rows.updateRow(row)
```